# sonarqube4.3 after upgrade php plugin (the version is 2.2) can not analysis magento project

Tags: sonarqube

It seems that cause by the Exception of : NullPointerException in class file org.sonar.php.checks.NonEmptyCaseWithoutBreakCheck . the code block is :

```
private boolean hasNoBreakComment(AstNode astNode) {
  for (Trivia trivia : astNode.getNextSibling().getToken().getTrivia()) {
   if (trivia.isComment() && trivia.toString().trim().contains("no break")) {
    return true;
   }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: In order to help our dev team, can you please post a code snippet to reproduce this error?

Comment: I have fixed this problem，I think this is a bug,May be some mistake in my database, it's cause a  NullPointerException in org.sonar.php.checks.NonEmptyCaseWithoutBreakCheck class, after changed under code,the problem been fixed!

```private boolean hasNoBreakComment(AstNode astNode) {
    if(null == astNode || null == astNode.getNextSibling()){
        return false;
    }
    for (Trivia trivia : astNode.getNextSibling().getToken().getTrivia()) {
      if (trivia.isComment() && trivia.toString().trim().contains("no break")) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

```

Comment: Could you still provide the piece of PHP code that caused the NPE please ? Indeed looks like it is a bug, so it would be nice to have reproducer to create a bug report. Thanks you!

Comment: `/**
 * Require necessary files
 */
require_once BP . '/app/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
(new \Magento\Framework\Autoload\IncludePath())->addIncludePath(array(BP . '/app/code', BP . '/lib'));
$classMapPath = BP . '/var/classmap.ser';
if (file_exists($classMapPath)) {
    require_once BP . '/lib/Magento/Framework/Autoload/ClassMap.php';
    $classMap = new \Magento\Framework\Autoload\ClassMap(BP);
    $classMap->addMap(unserialize(file_get_contents($classMapPath)));
    spl_autoload_register(array($classMap, 'load'), true, true);
}`

Comment: this file is in mangeto source code folder:app/bootstrap.php, when analysising the whole folder or analysising the app folder will cause this problem.

Comment: did your will fixed this bug?